# Trying to rename files in python but getting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename

I am trying to write a code to rename files to numbers but i keep getting this error
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Crypto Hood #100.jpg' -> ''` this is my code

```
os.chdir ('C:\\Users\\win 10\\Downloads\\Crypto Hood')
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.startswith('Crypto Hood #'):
        os.rename(filename, filename[100:])
```

Comment: As you can see, that file name is not 100 characters long, so you asking for `filename[100:]` returns a null string.  What were you really trying to do with that?

Comment: i am trying to rename the files

Comment: these are the name of the files Crypto Hood #50 e6tc.

Answer (score 0):

If we take:

```
filename = "Crypto Hood #100.jpg"
new_filename = filename[100:]
```

then `new_filename` would be an empty string (`''`) since `filename` only has 20 characters and you are slicing out the first 100. Empty strings are not valid filenames in Windows, so you get this error. I think you may be confused about how slicing works, so refer the doc: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you wanted to do this:

```
os.chdir ('C:\\Users\\win 10\\Downloads\\Crypto Hood')
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.startswith('Crypto Hood #'):
        newname = filename.split('#')[1]
        os.rename(filename, newname)
```